# Apache2 mod_write working for subdomain but not an IP address on same server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an Apache2 server running on CentOS 6.

There will be two subdomains running on this box.

```
sub1.domain.com
sub2.domain.com
```

For now the first subdomain is set up with DNS and mod_write working correctly. The second domain still has its DNS pointing to an older server and I will migrate the second domain's DNS to the new box's IP address.

Naturally I'm trying to test the new setup for sub2.domain.com before I migrate. I've configured the "default" web page for the box's IP address to have a document root which points to the future sub2.domain.com Laravel application.

mod_write rules in both .htaccess files are identical in both document roots and exactly match the recommended Laravel defaults.

Any insights appreciated as to why Apache2 would not process mod_write directives in an .htaccess file at a default document root accessed directly through an IP address much appreciated. I've combed through all the httpd.conf and vhost.conf files and nothing obvious sticks out as a likely culprit.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Rather than doing all that IP address business. Just modify your computers host file with the new ip address pointing to the sub2 domain then you will be able to test it. Host files are checked first so it won't use DNS. Before I go live I do this because I acutally like to see how it will work using the actual domain since users will not be using an ip address. http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-do-i-modify-my-hosts-file

Comment: Thank you, that's a nice suggestion and just out of curiosity I did try it. However, the root problem is that mod_rewrite is not working on the server side so even with an /etc/hosts trick I'm still experiencing the same problem. What I haven't been able to figure out is even though mod_rewrite is enabled and working on the other subdomain with .htaccess why is would the .htaccess file not work on the second subdomain on the same box. For now the only difference I am aware of is that one is being accessed through an IP and the other does have a DNS set up. Appreciate the response.

Comment: Do you have `AllowOverride All` also for the 2nd domain?

Comment: Thank you @PanamaJack I've used Apache for years and never knew about that directive. It appears to be the root of the problem and I'm trying to fix with AllowOverrideList. apachectl configtest is telling me
    Syntax error on line 305 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
Invalid command 'AllowOverrideList', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

But I think I'm on the right path. Thanks!

Comment: You are getting that error because I believe `AllowOverrideList` is an Apache 2.4 Directive. If you are using 2.2 it wont work. Which I'm pretty sure you are on Centos 6. Centos 7 comes with 2.4. You can get 2.4 on 6 but you will have to install it from another repo like Remi.